# Rails: Nokogiri issue, where to place code.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have a question regarding applying Nokogiri into my Rails app. I'm trying to collect baseball stats from a website and display the data into the view. I'm successful in parsing the data, however, I am not sure where to store the code in a RESTful manner.

Currently, I'm collecting the stats, putting them in an array and then matching them with another array (by rank, team, league, etc.). The two arrays are then put into a hash. Is there a more efficient way to do this (as in parse the data and then assign the data as a hash value, while the rank, team, league, etc. are assigned as hash keys)?

Lastly, I had placed the Nokogiri call into my controllers, but I do believe there is a better way. Ryan Bate's Railscasts suggests putting the Nokogiri call into a rake task (/lib/tasks/). Since, I want the website to receive the new baseball stats daily, will I have to run the rake task regularly? Secondly, how would I best implement the data into the view.

Searching online brought the idea of putting this into a config/initializers, but I'm not sure if that's a better solution.

The following is the Nokogiri call:

```
task :fetch_mets => :environment do 
  require 'nokogiri' 
  require 'open-uri' 

    url = "http..." 
    doc = Nokogiri::html(open(url)) 

    x = Array.new
    doc.css('tr:nth-child(14) td').each do |stat|
      x << stat.content 
    end 

    a = %w[rank team league games_total games_won games_lost ratio streak] 
    o = Hash[a.zip x] 

    statistics = Hash[o.amp{|(y,z)| [y.to_sym, z]}] 

    @order_stat = statistics.each{|key, value| puts #{key} is #{value}."}
end
```

Please let me know if I have to clarify anything, thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a table in your db called statistics and include all the keys in your hash (plus created_on and id). To save your stats do:

```
Statistic.new(statistics).save
```

Then in your view pull the one with the highest created_on.
For running rake tasks on a cron schedule take a look at [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever).

also it might be cleaner to do it more like:

```
keys = %w[rank team league games_total games_won games_lost ratio streak].map(&:to_sym)
values = doc.css('tr:nth-child(14) td').map(&:text)
statistics = Hash[keys.zip values]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This was extremely helpful, especially the clean code example.